# .net 6.0 Should database data be filtered via frontend or backend?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core

I have a bunch of images in a .cshtml file which can be clicked, toggling them on and off for a filter.

Below is an example of one

```
 <div id="attack">
                    <img class="skill-icon-deselected" src="images/Attack_icon_(detail).png" alt="Attack icon" />
                    <input class="skill-input" id="attack-level" placeholder="Attack Level" type="number" min="1" max=99 oninput="validity.valid||(value='');">
</div>
```

I am using entity framework to read from the database

```
        public List<Activity> allActivities = new List<Activity>();
        public void OnGet()
        {
            allActivities = _context.Activities.ToList();


        }
```

For further context I'm using razor pages

I'm unsure what the best solution is as I'm still new to front-end, potential things I've thought of:

1. pass data to the backend of which images are selected and filter on the backend before looping the list on the front end to display results
2. Passing the entire list through unfiltered and filtering on the front end

I'm going to assume through the backend as it makes sense for more "heavy lifting" to be done there from my limited knowledge

Comment: Define: "backend" - are you referring to the RDBMS specifically, or _all_ .NET code?

Comment: _"Passing the entire list through unfiltered and filtering on the front end"_ - if the list isn't too big (say, under a few kilobytes) then client-side filtering presents a much better UX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client-side filtering is for a small amount of data and is primarily for presentation purposes. Server side handles large amount data, and provides stability and scalability

check this [article](https://betterprogramming.pub/introduction-to-client-side-and-server-side-pagination-in-typescript-9edae72f94a0)